# How to handle LINQ to SQL schema changes

Tags: c#, wpf, linq-to-sql, visual-studio-2012, wix

I am creating a WPF project using LINQ to SQL and WiX for deployment.

I'm not sure how to handle database schema changes between minor or major updates to the application.

For example, how to handle updating a deployed v1.0.0.0 application to v1.0.1.0 which requires schema changes (either new or modified classes) to the existing database. If I were to just deploy the updated application it would crash as the existing database schema would not match the new code.

From my research I would imagine the simplified process would be to use something like [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to generate SQL ALTER scripts between v1.0.0.0 and v1.0.1.0 databases, and execute those change scripts during the WiX upgrade, but it seems like there would be a more 'built-in' approach to handle this more gracefully (the [Problem with Database Diffs](http://blog.liquibase.org/2007/06/the-problem-with-database-diffs.html) doesn't instill a lot of confidence).

Is detecting/tracking/deploying database changes possible entirely in WiX or Visual Studio?

`Edit:`

I should note that currently when we make changes to the code we are (at least in dev world) just dropping and recreating/repopulating our database with default data on runtime so that the LINQ to SQL `CreateDatabase()` just creates the schema based off the new code.

I see a lot of mention of using SQLMetal to generate dbml files, but I'm not using any sort of Designer for my database, we are doing 'code-first' if you will. This is where I am confused; do I *have* to use the dbml method then?

I've seen the Linq to Sql Database Synchronization open source projects ([CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36873/LINQ-to-SQL-Database-Synchronizer) and [CodePlex](https://linqtosqldbsync.codeplex.com/)) but one doesn't support SQL 2012 and the other errors out on not supporting Timestamp type and other errors that would require me to do a lot of customizations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I have decided to go with for now is as follows:

When deploying v1, save database as 'dbv1'.

When deploying v2, save database as 'dbv2', and in `Visual Studio > SQL > Schema Compare > New Comparison`

Source: dbv1, Target: dbv2

`Generate Script (Shift + Alt + G)`

This .sql script is then included in the WiX Upgrade Package as a `SqlScript` element.

It's not what I would desire - as you have to have a copy of the old database to compare with - but at least it doesn't require any expensive tools.